# Xamarin.Android - Dialog is not displayed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, dialog

I have a problem with my custom Dialog.
I want to show it while my application do something (in particular, creates a bitmap and does a HTTP request).
This is the portion of my code:

```
        LoadingDialog myLoading = new LoadingDialog();
        myLoading.Show()
        TakePicture();
        while (myPhotoFace == null) { }

        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        if (Connectivity.isConnected(context))
        {
            byte[] bytePhoto;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Constants.myGallery.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 40, stream);
                bytePhoto = stream.ToArray();
            }
            byte[] byteFace;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                myPhotoFace.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 40, stream);
                byteFace = stream.ToArray();
            }

            MediaEmotion myMedia = new MediaEmotion();
            string token = Utils.utils.GetParametro("token");

            myMedia.mediaID = 0;
            myMedia.face = byteFace;
            myMedia.photo = bytePhoto;

            var client = new RestClient("https://myServer.net/");
            var request = new RestRequest("/Controller/Method?token=" + token, Method.POST);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myMedia);
            request.AddParameter("stringaMediaEmotion", json);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Object myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(response.Content.ToString());
            [...]
```

After, I do something before start new activity.
As you can see, as a first operation I show my dialog (which, I verified, works correctly) but only appears as the last thing before moving on to the new activity. Also by simply trying to change the text of a textview the problem is the same. 
Why? What is the problem? How can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put all the network related code inside an async task: you'll free the main thread from network operation and the popup will appear until you'll move to another activity.

You can find some good examples and documentation here https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-with-async-await/